# Finding closest number

Tags: c++, function, file, visual-c++

I have the following .txt file:

```
23 43 -10
65 1 -1
-3 3 3
400 401 -389
21 6 -6
0 0 0
```

I need to write a program that will read data from the file until it reads the line with three 0’s.

I then need to write a function that accepts the three integer numbers and returns the number closest to 0. If two or three values are the same distance from 0 return the first number that is closest to 0.

This is what I have so far:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <cmath>

using namespace std;

int findClosest(int, int, int);

int main()
{
    ifstream fin;
    infile.open("LAB5DATA.TXT");

    int a, b, c;

    while (infile >> a >> b >> c && a + b + c != 0)
    {     
    int closest = findClosest(a, b, c);
    cout << closest << endl;
    }
    infile.close();
    return 0;
}

int findClosest(int a, int b, int c)
{
    int differenceA = abs(a - 0);
    int differenceB = abs(b - 0);
    int differenceC = abs(c - 0);

    int closest = differenceA;
    if (differenceB < closest)
        closest = differenceB;
    if (differenceC < closest)
        closest = differenceC;

    return closest;
}
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Put some effort into your `findClosest` function, and show us what you tried.  We won't do your homework for you.

Comment: `a + b + c != 0` have you thought what happens for, e. g., `a=3 b=-2 c=-1` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would fix your `findClosest` function by making a couple of changes. First off, define a function that takes the absolute of an integer so that you can compare the differences more cleanly.

Then from there, simply return the minimum of the 3 differences.

Edited:

```
int findClosest(int a, int b, int c)
{
    int closest = a;
    if (abs(b) < abs(a)) closest = b;
    if (abs(c) < abs(b)) closest = c;
    return closest;
}
```

Comment: Neil, you should answer the question instead of putting comments. When you have enough points you can make comments in the comment section. Of course you can add comments in this section because it's your post.

Comment: Sorry about that, I just don't think that providing him a full solution will teach him very much. Pseudocode should suffice to guide him, but since you've provided the solution I guess the deed is done.